# Wake up in the middle of night

Tags: word-request

> Yesterday, I suddenly woke up at midnight in the middle of terrible dream.

Sometimes, when you have bad dream, you wake up suddenly scared. So when say about this to another person, what is better word to use instead of "woke up"?

I came to know about a word "bolts up". But I'm for some other word that native speaker use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a better word. A large majority of the time, I'd probably use the verb *wake*  in that context.

There's the verb *started*, which means:

> **start** (*verb*) give a small jump or make a sudden jerking movement from surprise or alarm (NOAD)

but that word also means *to begin*, and is seen more often in that context, so I couldn't say that *started* is a "better" word, even if it is closer to the meaning you want.

Some ways you could intensify "woke up" might include:

- I was suddenly **jarred awake**...
- I was suddenly **jolted awake**...
- I suddenly **woke up startled**...

If you look through [this search result](http://www.google.com/#q=jolted+awake&safe=off&tbm=bks&ei=X7OpUf36NJLY9QT5h4GQDA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.eWU&fp=bea39bf346c5740f&biw=1300&bih=862) and [this search result](http://www.google.com/#safe=off&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22jarred+awake%22&oq=%22jarred+awake%22&gs_l=serp.3...8948.9925.5.10739.2.2.0.0.0.0.133.251.0j2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.15.psy-ab.EUPqpH5FRm0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.eWU&fp=bea39bf346c5740f&biw=1300&bih=862), you'll see several instances of *jolted awake* and *jarred awake* in published works.